# I want to split an arraylist carrying multiple records from a database in java

Tags: java, database, arraylist

i'm retrieving all the records of a table called employees from a database in an arraylist and i want to split this arraylist as it saves in another list each record by index .

```
    public void settexttotextview(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            JSONObject json=null;
            try {
                 json=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                 s.add(json.getString("userid")+json.getString("name")
                          +json.getString("overtime")); 
                 List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
                 list.add(i, s);        
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // TODO: handle exception
        }   
    }
    adapter.add(s);
```

Comment: oh , sorry .. i've formatted it

Comment: im having an phpmyadmin database and im retrieving all the tuples of the table in an arraylist and i want to split this arraylist to get each tuple separated alone and save it with an index in another list

Comment: But your code is not working? What errors do you get?

Comment: i'm having no errors but whenever i set the adapter with the arraylist that saves the employees info it shows all the records in the same index so i need to split this arraylist into sublists each sublist carries only one record from the table ,, for example this code retrieve all the records from the table like that (1 john null,2 robert null ,3 christian null) however i need it to be like that : (1 john null) , (2 robert null) .... each in a separate list

Comment: Looking at it, i think you need to initialize the `s` list again in the `try` block so it will be a new list, you are now using `list` instead of `s`. Move `list` out of the `for` loop. Shouldn't the adapter add `list` instead of `s`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code it seems there is nothing happening with the `list` list.

Not sure if this is the solution, but try:

```
public void settexttotextview(JSONArray jsonArray) {

    List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    List<String> s;
    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject json=null;
        try {
             s = new ArrayList<String>(); 
             json=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
             s.add(json.getString("userid")+json.getString("name")
                      +json.getString("overtime")); 
             list.add(i, s); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO: handle exception
    }   
}
adapter.add(list); // not sure what adapter is.
```